# How to seal between aluminum downspout and PVC adapter?

Tags: caulking, gutters, french-drain

I recently connected a gutter downspout to an existing French drain along the side of my house. The old downspout poured out onto the patio which would ice over in winter. Because of how the French drain is situated, and since there's a lot going on along this corner of the house, the top of the PVC adapter sits right at ground level.

I understand normally this adapter would be flush against the house and higher above ground and wouldn't need sealant, but in this case since it's right at ground level I'd like to fill it in to prevent it from filling with soil and eventually weeds.

I tried sealing the gap with some old silicone, but that ended up being past it's prime (didn't cure properly), so I need to go buy something else. **Will any old exterior caulking do? Or should I buy something specific?**

(Pardon my dog who took advantage of my distracted state to escape as I was taking this picture.)

[image: Downspout to PVC adapter]

Comment: Get some premium non-expired silicone and it should last for years, if not decades. Silicone has excellent UV resistance; polyurethane calks do not. Do not get some acrylic/latex-based garbage. 100% pure silicone, period.

Comment: I don’t like to seal connections like that up tight. I like a small uniform gap so water will spill out if there is a clog. It’s like an alarm to alert me to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Some fresh silicone sealant should do it for you. Clean the rim of the adaptor removing all of the old sealant and apply the caulk around the pipe being sure to get it down between the fittings.